# MySQL CPU Maxing - 600%

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Currently have a MySQL database and experiencing an issue with MySQL running at 600% of the CPU usage.

What changes can be made to the my.cnf file?

6 CPU's

32GB of RAM

250GB Hard Drive.

```
#/etc/mysql/my.cnf: The global mysql configuration file.
# $Id$
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password                                       = your_password
port                                            = 3306
socket                                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysql]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqladmin]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlcheck]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqldump]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlimport]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqlshow]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets
default-character-set=utf8

[myisamchk]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets

[myisampack]
character-sets-dir=/usr/share/mysql/charsets

# use [safe_mysqld] with mysql-3
[mysqld_safe]
err-log                                         = /var/log/mysql/mysql.err

# add a section [mysqld-4.1] or [mysqld-5.0] for specific configurations
[mysqld]
character-set-server                            = utf8
user                                            = mysql
port                                            = 3306
socket                                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file                                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
#log-error                                      = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.err
        basedir                                 = /usr
        datadir                                 = /var/lib/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size                                 = 128M
max_allowed_packet                              = 16M
table_open_cache                                = 400
sort_buffer_size                                = 4M
net_buffer_length                               = 16K
read_buffer_size                                = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size                            = 1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size                         = 512M
max_connections                                 = 1000
connect_timeout                                 = 5
wait_timeout                                    = 60
query_cache_type                                = 1
query_cache_limit                               = 4M
query_cache_size                                = 128M
table_cache                                     = 2500
thread_cache_size                               = 128
performance_schema                              = ON
skip-name-resolve
lc_messages_dir                                 = /usr/share/mysql

#Set this to your desired error message language
lc_messages                                     = en_US

# security:
# using "localhost" in connects uses sockets by default
# skip-networking
  bind-address                                  = 0.0.0.0

  log-bin
  server-id                                       = 1

# point the following paths to different dedicated disks
  tmpdir                                          = /tmp/
#log-update                             = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# you need the debug USE flag enabled to use the following directives,
# if needed, uncomment them, start the server and issue
# #tail -f /tmp/mysqld.sql /tmp/mysqld.trace
# this will show you *exactly* what's happening in your server ;)

#log                                            = /tmp/mysqld.sql
#gdb

#debug                                          = d:t:i:o,/tmp/mysqld.trace
   #one-thread

   # the rest of the innodb config follows:
   # don't eat too much memory, we're trying to be safe on 64Mb boxes
   # you might want to bump this up a bit on boxes with more RAM
     innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
     innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
   #
   # i'd like to use /var/lib/mysql/innodb, but that is seen as a database    :-(
   # and upstream wants things to be under /var/lib/mysql/, so that's the route
   # we have to take for the moment
   #innodb_data_home_dir           = /var/lib/mysql/
   #innodb_log_arch_dir            = /var/lib/mysql/
   #innodb_log_group_home_dir      = /var/lib/mysql/
   # you may wish to change this size to be more suitable for your system
   # the max is there to avoid run-away growth on your machine
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:20G
   # we keep this at around 25% of of innodb_buffer_pool_size
   # sensible values range from 1MB to (1/innodb_log_files_in_group*innodb_buffer_pool_size)
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
   # this is the default, increase it if you have very large transactions going on
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
   # this is the default and won't hurt you

   # you shouldn't need to tweak it
     innodb_log_files_in_group=2
# see the innodb config docs, the other options are not always safe
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_file_per_table = 1

# Uncomment this to get FEDERATED engine support
#plugin-load=federated=ha_federated.so
loose-federated

thread_concurrency = 12

long_query_time = 10
#slow-query-log = 1
#slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysqld_slow_query.log

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet                      = 16M

[mysql]
# uncomment the next directive if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size                         = 20M
sort_buffer_size                        = 20M
read_buffer                             = 2M
write_buffer                            = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size                         = 20M
sort_buffer_size                        = 20M
read_buffer_size                        = 2M
write_buffer_size                       = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mariadb]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL CPU Maxing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165465/mysql-cpu-maxing)

Answer (score 1):

High CPU --> Inadequate indexes and/or queries in need of tweaking.

Set `long_query_time = 1` so you can catch faster, but more common, slow queries.  And turn on the slow-log.  (They are commented out.)  After the log has been running for some time, use `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest`, then let's look at the first couple of queries.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

It is very rare to be able to fix high CPU via `my.cnf`.